# Count or read only actual entries

Tags: octave

How can I count or read only the actual entries of a column, as distinct from non-zero entries?

In other words, if I have the file:

```
4000,1,5221,0
4001,0,5222,1
4002,3,,,
```

column 4 has 2 actual entries, whereof one vanishes. I can count entries like so:

```
R = csvread("bugtest.csv");

for i = 1:4
VanishingColEntries(i) = numel (find (R(:,i) ==0));
NonVanishingColEntries(i) = nnz(R(:,i));
endfor
VanishingColEntries
NonVanishingColEntries
```

yielding:

```
octave:2> nument
VanishingColEntries =

   0   1   1   2

NonVanishingColEntries =

   3   2   2   1
```

But, I dont know how to extract the number of "actual" entries, that is the sum of non zero and explicitly zero entries!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csvread` is only for numeric data. If `csvread` encounters an entry which is not strictly numeric, it checks if the string starts with a number, and uses that as the result (e.g. `1direction, 2pac, 7up` will result in `1,2,7` ). 'Empty' entries here are effectively considered to be an empty string, which is parsed as the number 0. However, there are some special strings, like `nan` and `inf` which are parsed specially.

If you can / are happy to preprocess your csv file, then you can replace all empty entries with the string `nan` (without quotes). `csvread` will then treat this string specially and replace it with an actual `nan` value in the resulting numerical matrix. You can then use this with `isnan` to count the number of nan / non-nan entries as follows:

```matlab
  R = csvread( 'bugtest.csv' );

% Count nan / non-nan entries along rows
  VanishingColEntries    = sum(  isnan( R ), 1 )
  NonVanishingColEntries = sum( ~isnan( R ), 1 )
```

If you do not have the luxury of preprocessing your csv file (or you simply want to process it programmatically throughout, without the need for human intervention), then you can use the `csv2cell` function from the `io` package instead, and process the resulting cell to get what you want, e.g.

```matlab
  pkg load io
  C = csv2cell( 'bugtest.csv' )

% Convert cells with empty strings to nan
  for i = 1 : numel(C), if ischar(C{i}), C{i} = nan; endif, endfor

% Convert numeric cell array (nan is a valid number) to a matrix
  R = cell2mat( C );
```

You can then use `isnan` as before to get your result.

Comment: You could use  `C(cellfun(@isempty, C))=NaN;`  in place of the `for` loop and the `if` condition. `for`, `if`, `endif`, and `endfor` in single-line don't look nice to me. But it is probably just me. Good idea with `csv2cell` btw

Comment: @SardarUsama I prefer for loops instead of cellfun in SO answers specifically, in case it creates more confusion ... but otherwise I agree that looks much nicer :)  Btw, I used `ischar` over `isempty` on purpose, because while it's impied from the given data that empty slots will not contain spaces, this is not specified (and `' '` counts as non-empty!)

Comment: :D I was actually wondering why you used `ischar`. Insightful!